# Appium: How to dismiss an iOS modal without a Close button

Tags: appium, ui-automation, appium-ios, python-appium

I'm trying to automate an iOS app's UI for testing purposes.  I'm having trouble closing/dismissing a modal that does not have a `Close` button.

I'm using Appium (Python) to automate actions and the Inspector tells me that all other elements "behind" the modal are `visible: false` ... so if I `tap_settings` to open the modal, `tap_settings` to close the modal doesn't work.

When I `tap_settings` to dismiss the modal, my code continues without failing *but* the following assertion fails because the modal persists.

I've also tried the 6 actions below:

```
    #1
    el = driver.find_element_by_name('Settings')
    action = TouchAction(driver)
    action.press(el)

    #2
    return TouchAction(driver).press(None, 10, 10).perform()

    #3
    return TouchAction(driver).tap(driver.find_element_by_name('Settings')).perform()

    #4
    return profile_settings().clear()

    #5
    return driver.execute_script("mobile: tap", {'x': 0, 'y': 0})

    #6
    return driver.swipe(0, 0, 10, 10)
```

Has anyone run into this or something similar?  Or any ideas I haven't tried?

Answer (score 1):

@rHenderson- Try adding below code, after performing actions on the `modal`

```
self.driver.press_keycode(10);
```

Other that above, pressing back key might also help closing the `modal` if it is supported by your app.

Comment: thank you @prerna pal ! but that didn't work: "error":"unknown method","message":"Method has not yet been implemented"

Comment: Did you also try clicking on android back button? 
Sample code:
driver.pressKeyCode(AndroidKeyCode.BACK);
or
driver.navigate().back();